# Cant find Android 7.1.1 For Update in SDK Manager

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-7.0-nougat

I want to update Android 7.1.1 but I am getting **Android Null** :D

[image]

Is there any solution. Did anyone got this type of issue?

Comment: I can't see SDK platform for API 25 available in standalone SDK manager. I don't think that you can and should do anything about it. I believe it is gonna be fixed soon

Comment: I am too getting the same...but if you launch standalone SDK manager then you can see...7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

> **Important**: To download the most recent Android system components from the Android SDK Manager, you must first update the SDK Tools to the most recent release and restart the SDK Manager. If you do not, the latest Android system packages may not be available for download.

From: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

Run android.bat in tools directory to update sdk